# Warning: closing unused connection n

Tags: r, warnings, readline

```
getCommentary=function(){
    Commentary=readLines(file("C:\\Commentary\\com.txt"))
    return(Commentary)
    close(readLines)
    closeAllConnections()
}
```

I have no idea what is wrong with this function. When I run this in R, it keeps giving me the following warning:

```
Warning message:
closing unused connection 5 ("C:\\Commentary\\com.txt")
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`readLines()` is a function, you don't `close()` it. You want to close the connection opened by the `file()` function. Also, you are `return()`ing *before* you close any connections. As far as the function is concerned, the lines after the `return()` statement don't exist.

One option is to save the object returned by the `file()` call, as you shouldn't be closing all connections only those your function opens. Here is a non-function version to illustrate the idea:

```
R> cat("foobar\n", file = "foo.txt")
R> con <- file("foo.txt")
R> out <- readLines(con)
R> out
[1] "foobar"
R> close(con)
```

To write your function, however, I would probably take a slightly different tack:

```
getCommentary <- function(filepath) {
    con <- file(filepath)
    on.exit(close(con))
    Commentary <-readLines(con)
    Commentary
}
```

Which is used as follows, with the text file created above as an example file to read from

```
R> getCommentary("foo.txt")
[1] "foobar"
```

I used `on.exit()` so that once `con` is created, if the function terminates, for whatever reason, the connection will be closed. If you left this just to a `close(con)` statement just before the last line, e.g.:

```
    Commentary <-readLines(con)
    close(con)
    Commentary
}
```

the function could fail on the `readLines()` call and terminate, so the connection would not be closed. `on.exit()` would arrange for the connection to be closed, even if the function terminates early.

Comment: @hadley's comment is wise (unsurprisingly): prefer base behavior that's well-constructed to manage connections over dealing with them yourself. Having said that, I voted the above answer up for it's illustration of `on.exit`, for the general case where that wise advice doesn't apply.

Comment: @MattTenenbaum : So if I open a file using `var1 <- readLines("filename.txt",encoding="UTF-8")`. I need not close it right?